# Custom form template - yesno select box html

Tags: admin, adminhtml, frontend, forms

Is it possible either in a block or template (adminhtml) to render a yes/no select box directly?

Without having to get the option array first and then build the select manually?

I would have thought there be an existing method somewhere that does this but I can not find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
$options = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toOptionArray();

//if outside of a controller or block, use Mage::app()->getLayout()
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
            ->setName($name)
            ->setId($attribute->getAttributeCode())
            ->setTitle($this->getAttributeLabel($attribute))
            ->setExtraParams("")
            ->setValue($this->getAttributeValue($attribute))
            ->setOptions($options)
            ->getHtml();
```

Which, depending on the values of $name, $attribute, etc (for testing I just put in random data) you wind up with the following output:

```
<select name="name" id="4" class="" title="mytitle" ><option value="1" >Yes</option><option value="0" selected="selected" >No</option></select>
```

Which makes me think maybe you should just do it **the old-fashioned way**:

```
<select name="myselectbox" id="myid">
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
```

I kid, I kid. Or do I?

Comment: I was hoping for some helper that spat out the yesno select box.  If thats not the case then i thinnk the old fashioned way is best also :)

Comment: A helper for you: https://gist.github.com/philwinkle/6300135